# Is there any current public blockchain technology that allows users to post a publicly viewable document directly on a blockchain?

Tags: blockchain

I have read that Ethereum can theoretically support large documents (1 MB), but that such transactions would be very expensive and they risk not being validated.

Most blockchain document services I have found assign a hash to a document then put the hash on the blockchain, but I am wondering if any blockchain ledgers exist that just put the whole document on the blockchain, effectively making the document itself 'immutable'?

I am brand new to this technology and I don't know its limitations or capabilities: most blockchain terminology and technology is just over my head.

Comment: You should take a look at https://filecoin.io/